# Change source image for image view when pressed

Tags: android

I have a scroll view with lots of image buttons. I want to change the image for an image button when it's pressed. The thing is that I want the image to remain until another image button is pressed. That's why I couldn't use a selector. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 35):

You want to do this.

```
ImageButton Demo_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.firstimage);

// when you click this demo button
Demo_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Demo_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
    }
}
```

Try this. (updated setset to set)

Comment: Hi PrashantAdesara. I know this would work (I would have to set the unselected image for the previous clicked view though). I was thinking at a more natural approach. Like to create a custom image view and set the current resource image in there (for example in the setSelected method). The problem is that I need a view method that is called when the view is selected and unselected. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 23):

Better solution, use the following xml as source of the image:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_activated="true">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_selected"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_not_selected"/>
        </item>
    </selector>

    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
     }
```

Comment: See also my answer which is shorter and doesn't require Java code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239629/245966 (and also it generates preview in Android Studio)

Answer (score 21):

### The shortest way to achieve it, using only XML (no Java code):

Save the following as `drawable/image_pressable.xml` next to the two images:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_regular" />
</selector>
```

then reference it as:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/image_pressable" />
```

Tip:

Using `state_pressed` instead of `state_activated` allows the image to be changed when pressing it with the fingers. `state_activated` could be useful, if you want to dynamically change the status of the ImageView, but not if you just want it to behave different when pressed, without any code involved. Which is exactly what it was asked in the question of this topic.

Comment: Simply brilliant. Straightforward, clear and complete answer. The one from @M. Usman Khan is almost as great as this one, but lacks a better explanation.

Comment: Works perfect. Just one remark, you might need to set the clickable attribute of the ImageView: `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 6):

the OnTouchListener is much better for what you have to do:

```
myImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
myImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_when_pressed);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
myImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_when_released);
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

Comment: It's better than calling `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_when_pressed)` and `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_when_released)` one after another in `onClick()`. If the user holds the image, the resource will remain `image_when_pressed` until they release the button

Answer (score 5):

don't forget to create the field "fun"

Try this for changing image.When **imageview** is pressed

```
Like_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            **private boolean fun = true;**


            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(fun)
                {
                Like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlike);
                fun=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    fun=true;       
                    Like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: hello...suppose im performing this one activity.user click to glow image... what if user goes from one activity to another and again coming back to activity one will the button remain as glow?

Answer (score 5):

try below code :-

```
boolean flag=false;
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn);

// when you click this demo button
btn .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!flag) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageonpress);
        flag=true;  
    }
    else {
          btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
          flag=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hello...suppose im performing this one activity.user click to glow image... what if user goes from one activity to another and again coming back to activity one will the button remain as glow?

Answer (score 4):

```
ImageButton Demo_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.firstimage);
ImageButton second_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.secondimage);

// when you click this demo button
Demo_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Demo_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
    second_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);
   }
}

second_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Demo_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);
      second_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
   }
}
```

I Hope u want to like that
Right???

Comment: Not really. I was looking for a scroll view with views, in which, if you select a view, the last selected gets unselected. Your example works for 2 buttons, and the selection is done manually.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was:

I created a new drawable xml file, for eg, image_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_pressed"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And in my layout file, I set the src of the imageView as:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_state"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float alpha_first = 0.2f;
float alpha_second = 1.0f;
    AlphaAnimation alphadp = new AlphaAnimation(alpha_second, alpha_first);
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.disable_deactivate_pic:
        ImageButton disable_button =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.disable_deactivate_pic);
                if (!flag) {
                    disable_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.enable_active);

                    linearLayout_for_picture = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_imageView_pic);

                alphadp.setFillAfter(true);
                linearLayout_for_picture.startAnimation(alphadp);
                flag=true;
                }
        else {
                    disable_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.disable_active);
                    alphadp.setFillAfter(false);
                    linearLayout_for_picture.startAnimation(alphadp);
                    flag=false;
                }

            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StateListDrawable` to achieve this. This method also works for `ImageButton`s. I prefer it to setting additional listeners.

I've also compiled a class of additional helpers: http://alexanderwong.me/post/40799636705/android-change-background-image-drawable-on-press

```
    public static StateListDrawable makeStateDrawable(Drawable drawable, Drawable pressedDrawable, Drawable disabledDrawable) {
    boolean set = false;
    StateListDrawable stateDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    if (disabledDrawable != null) {
        set = true;
        stateDrawable.addState(new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_enabled }, disabledDrawable);
    }
    if (pressedDrawable != null) {
        set = true;
        stateDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, pressedDrawable);
    }
    if (drawable != null) {
        set = true;
        stateDrawable.addState(new int[0], drawable);
    }
    return set ? stateDrawable : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`state_pressed` or `state_activated` **did not work for me**.

However, I succeeded with `state_enabled`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off" />
</selector>
```

Your xml should declare it as src:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_checkmark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbox_selector_filter"/>
```

Then in code, ensure you enable or disable it based on event/state:

`imageCheckBox.isEnabled = true`

This was easiest and cleanest for me

Answer (score 0):

If you save the selection on click and then reload the image scroll gallery (or scroll menu) and then reload and scroll to the selection with a replaced image, then you might be able to do it.  As far as I know none of the inbuilt gallery or menu functions have the ability to replace images once they are loaded and displayed.

Comment: I was thinking of something like creating a custom button, and using a method (like onSelected but to be called with false, when another button is selected) to set the current image.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an `ImageView` or`ImageButton` and want to change image of that when its pressed, you can refresh activity for any pressed:

```
 fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int isFavor = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("isFavor"));
            if(isFavor == 1){
                db.execSQL("update content set isFavor=0 where ID="+idxx+";");
                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favnot_ic);

                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"item cleaned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                activity.finish();
                activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                context.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
            }
            else{
                db.execSQL("update content set isFavor=1 where ID=" + idxx + ";");
                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_ic);
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Item added...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                activity.finish();
                activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                context.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if u have already a button in ur app that will do the swap between the two pics u have when its clicked then there is a simple Code :D

// to add Images in android we simply " Copy them from their location and past in (res --> drawable)"

// then drag and drop "ImageView" and select the image u want to display

// u can adjust the scale throw "scaleType , layout_Width & layout_Height"

```
public boolean swap = true;

public  void change(View view)
{
    ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    if (swap)
    {
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
        swap=false;
    }
    else
    {
        swap=true;
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.couple);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's too late to answer. But someones may get help from this answer.

**It's working like charm -**

```
circularImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        circularImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_edit_photo);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        circularImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_male_8);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.i("ImageViewEvent", "Action_Move_Called");    
                        break;
                }
                return true; // Note: This return value must need to be true if you want to call MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: action. 
            }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Demo_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage)

//Demo_button is your event holder (the button or imageview or bitmap file which contains the image) and secondimage is your image (drawable) file, without any complications.
```

This does the trick.