# Issue on changing the resource in imageView when that imageView is pressed

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to write an application to change the image resource, when that imageView is pressed.

I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193167/change-source-image-for-image-view-when-pressed).

I used both `setOnTouchListener` and `setOnClickListener` in my code. In both, i would get logs. BUt, image didn't change. I have given my code below:

```
ImageView more;
 more = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
```

`setOnTouchListener` is:

```
more.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG,"Event type "+event+" "+ event.getAction());
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

My `setOnClickListener` is:

```
 more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!buttonClicked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... false" + buttonClicked);
                    buttonClicked = true;
                    more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                }
                if (buttonClicked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... true" + buttonClicked);
                    buttonClicked = false;
                    more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
                }
                // more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 /* Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... " + pos);
                 * if(listData.getPosition() == SUBSCRIBE) {
                 * more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                 * //more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1); Log.d(TAG,
                 * "For Subscribe..................."); intent = new
                 * Intent(getContext(), EpisodeActivity.class);
                 * intent.putExtra("URL", strurl);
                 * getContext().startActivity(intent);
                 * 
                 * } else { // TODO REWRITE IT FOR ADDING AS A FAVIOURITE ITEMS
                 * Log.d(TAG, "For Episode..................."); }
                 */

            }
        });
```

Please point out what mistake i have done.

Thank you in advance!!!

**NOTE:** Since I want this changes in `listView` for `ListItem images`, I am using this code inside the `Custom Adapter`

**UPDATE:**

my adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapterForSubcribe extends ArrayAdapter<ListData> {

    public final String TAG = "CustomAdapterForSubcribe";
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    boolean buttonClicked = false;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    TextView title, desc;
    ImageView more, fav, imageRightSubscribe, imageRightEpisode;
    Intent intent;
    public static int SUBSCRIBE = 1;
    public static int EPISODE = 0;
    private String strurl = "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss";
    private String imageUrlEpisode = "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/66996000/jpg/_66996549_66996528.jpg";

    public CustomAdapterForSubcribe(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            List<ListData> objects, int option) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int pos = position;
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_row_view, parent, false);
        }
        final ListData listData = getItem(position);

        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description);
        more = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        if (listData.getPosition() == SUBSCRIBE) {
            more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
        } else {
            more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_1);
        }
        // more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
        imageRightEpisode = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageRightEpisode.setTag(imageUrlEpisode);
        new DownloadImagesTask().execute(imageRightEpisode);
        more.setTag(new Integer(position));

        if (listData.getPosition() == SUBSCRIBE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "<<<<.....In option.....>>>>");
            desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            // title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextSize(16);
            title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        }
        title.setText(listData.getTitle());
        desc.setText(listData.getDesc());
//      more.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
//
//          @Override
//          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              Log.d(TAG, "Event type " + event + " " + event.getAction());
//              if (listData.getPosition() == SUBSCRIBE) {
//                  switch (event.getAction()) {
//
//                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//                      Log.d(TAG, "SUBSCRIBE...Image press releasing....");
//                      more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
//                      more.invalidate();
//                      break;
//                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//                      Log.d(TAG, "SUBSCRIBE... Image pressing....");
//                      more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
//                      break;
//                  }
//              }
//
//              return false;
//          }
//      });
        more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listData.getPosition() == EPISODE) {
                    if (!buttonClicked) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... false" + pos);

                        more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_2);
                        buttonClicked = true;
                    }
                    else if (buttonClicked) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... " + buttonClicked);

                        more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_1);
                        buttonClicked = false;
                    }
                }

                // more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                else if (listData.getPosition() == SUBSCRIBE) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... " + pos);
                    Log.d(TAG, "For Subscribe...................");
                    intent = new Intent(getContext(), EpisodeActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("URL", strurl);
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    // TODO REWRITE IT FOR ADDING AS A FAVIOURITE ITEMS
                    Log.d(TAG, "For Episode...................");
                }

            }
        });

        return row;
    }
```

Even Somewhat i changed in my code, TouchClickListener didn't work for my image

Comment: Did you get any exception? I don´t think that it will take an effect, but please try more.invalidate(R.drawable.yourDrawable); after change the image, does it work?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, I didn't get any exception. it also didn't work

Comment: ok, another try. just set the change of the image before You set boolean buttonClick. first: more.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourDrawable); - and after that buttonClicked = false. Do this in all events. It is just an assumption but maybe the image is not changed, because Your if statement says: change the image if buttonClicked==true.But You  set buttonClicked  to false and after that You try to change the image, so the if statement is not true anymore. But like I said, it is just an assumption

Comment: It didn't work. After coming inside if only we do buttonClicked = false na? It never change anything.

Comment: no, I meant:  public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!buttonClicked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... false" + buttonClicked);     more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                    buttonClicked = true;
                    
                }
                if (buttonClicked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "on image click..... true" + buttonClicked);       more.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
                    buttonClicked = false;
                   
                } I  don´t want to set it as an answer, I don´t know if it works.

Comment: OK, for now I got no possibility to test it myself, but later if I am at home I will give it a try, if You got no solution until then. Please post a little bit more code. I need to see Your custom adapter.

Comment: Thank you so much... I was updated..

Comment: hi there, tried some stuff but got a question. Is it possible for You to initialize the imageView you want to change inside the adapter and not from the beginning? Do You need to set this imageView onClickListener? I think You will get more success if You set Your listView onItemClickListener and then just change the image at item click.

Comment: No, i want to change the image, when clicking of that image only. If i  use onItemClickListener, the whole item will be selected na? Actually my aim is, when click on that image, it will be behave like a button, thats y i want to change the image.

Comment: ah ok, so You got more than one imageView in one listItem?Tricky.....

Comment: another idea: set the ListView onItemClickListener, define some finals, for example final int IMAGE_VIEW_1=1; final int IMAGE_VIEW_2=2 and int PRESSED_IMAGE = 0; Every time You press an imageView set PRESSED_IMAGE=IMAGE_VIEW_1 or PRESSED_IMAGE=IMAGE_VIEW_2. Then, on onItemClickListener, check which one is pressed and do some switch/case: switch(PRESSED_IMAGE){ case(IMAGE_VIEW_1): ...... and so on. In that case your favorite imageVIew is pressed, change the Image. I think the problem is, you can´t change resource inside resources buttonClickListener easily.

Comment: Hey, i got a solution...:) Thank u for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `Holder` and I changed `if` condition instead of `Switch` case

My Working code is:

```
holder.more.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (listData.getPosition() == SUBSCRIBE) {

                        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                            Log.d(TAG,"releasing.....");
                            holder.fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_1);
                        }
                        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            Log.d(TAG,"pressing.....");
                            holder.fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_2);
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```