# button change drawable on holding

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable

I'm trying to make this volume button that changes the drawable according to the state that it is put in. So on default the Volume of the device will be on, when pressed it will mute the device, and when its held it'll change the device to vibrating only. Now I am trying to change the drawable of when its put on vibrating, but nothing I try seems to work. I currently have this code in my XML, and I tried playing around with the pressed state but I couldn't get something to work that changes the drawable accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_down_black_24dp"
    android:state_checked="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_off_black_24dp"
    android:state_checked="false"/>    
</selector>
```

Comment: What i got, In your case there are  3 states(on,off, vibrate). and with selector you can handle two state checked and unchecked . I think you should do it at runtime for 3rd state.  For two states use <bitmap> tag in selector .

Comment: I'd have to figure out how to do that, but I was afraid this was probably the only option, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `android:state_pressed`.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_you_want_on_press_state"
android:state_pressed="true" />`
```

Hope this Help.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it doesn't switch to the drawable when the button is hold.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new drawable xml file, for eg, image_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_pressed"/>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</item>
</selector>
```

And in my layout file, I set the src of the imageView as:

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/image_state"/>
```

Also check this :
     [Change source image for image view when pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193167/change-source-image-for-image-view-when-pressed)

Comment: I am using a togglebutton, but I basically did the same. Made the xml I pasted above in its own xml file and linked the drawable source to that. I'm not sure how this is different, isn't this just the same in the end? I want the drawables to stay on the select option as well. Thats why I used the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

Default drawable `<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_off_black_24dp"></item>` and for the pressed st `<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_down_black_24dp" android:state_pressed="true" />`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="200">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_down_black_24dp" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_down_black_24dp" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_off_black_24dp"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Do you mean drawable instead of color? And when I tried this it shows the vibration between switching options, and it does show the vibration drawable when the button is hold, but it doesn't stay on the vibration drawable as it should.

Comment: Sorry, i have changed my answer. Please look check it. You have to use drawable not color. I have copy-paste code that's why its color.

Comment: I changed it to this :
`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="200">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_down_black_24dp" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vibration_black_24dp" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_off_black_24dp"></item>
</selector>`

but it doesn't stay on the drawable when pressed.

Comment: Means when button is hold you want to change drawable?

Comment: Yeah in every state, I want to drawable to stay, just like on your phone. So when I mute the sound, I want to change the drawble to the mute icon and stay there. If I hold the button, I want the state to change to vibration and the drawable to stay on its vibration drawable. The code behind this already works, but I can't have the vibration drawable stay.