# Change source image for all backgrounds when imageview is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I would like to change the background of all the layers when I click an `ImageView`, for example this `ImageView` has the preview of yellow color but when I click it, I would like to change the background to an image with the name of `fondoamarillo.jpg`, my layer name is `colores` and my kt is `Colores`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainln"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoazul">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="71dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iccol" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/coloress" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:onClick="onAtrasConfig"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/atras" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView42"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="214dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView44"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView45"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/verde" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView45"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView41"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aguamarina" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView41"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:onClick="changeAllBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/amarillo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView46"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="214dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView42"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView43"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rosa" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView44"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="214dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView41"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/azul" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView43"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView45"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rojo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the `.kt`:

```
class Colores : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.colores)
    }

    fun onAtrasConfig(view: View){
        try {
            val intent: Intent = Intent(this, Configuracion::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun changeAllBackground(mainLayout:View) {
        val mainln: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainln)
        mainln.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)
    }
}
```

[image: This is my xml and I would like to click the imageView or Button "it doesn't matter which one if it works" to change the image of the layout background]

[image: This should be the new background when I click the new imageView or Button]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change source image for image view when pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193167/change-source-image-for-image-view-when-pressed)

Comment: I changed the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then you can use this function that I just created. it always needs the Layout of your views holder. for example if you want to catch all layers then you can send the main layout of yours and it doesn't matter which kind is your main layout all is good to go and will change the background to the image you have told me.

**Java Version:**

```
    private void changeAllBackground(ViewGroup mainLayout){
        for(int i=0; i<mainLayout.getChildCount();i++){
            View v = mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
            //this is where you put what you want to do with the layer
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo);
            if(v instanceof ViewGroup)
                changeAllBackground(((ViewGroup)v));
        }
    }
```

**Kotlin version:**

```
private fun changeAllBackground(mainLayout:ViewGroup) {
  for (i in 0 until mainLayout.getChildCount())
  {
    val v = mainLayout.getChildAt(i)
    //this is where you put what you want to do with the layer
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)
    if (v is ViewGroup){
        changeAllBackground((v as ViewGroup))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you taking as a viewgroup?

Comment: just import it. just import the ViewGroup is a class. for example, the LinearLayout is the child of ViewGroup. if you are using android studio then just click Alt + Enter in the ViewGroup word and will import it.

Comment: this is definitely your answer.as you can see the StackOverflow itself got the ViewGroup as a defined name so it means that it is not unresolved just import it.

Comment: this is the import code if you cant do it: ```import android.view.ViewGroup;``` and it's for java just convert it to Kotlin. if you don't know how just tell me I will change it for you the directory of both is the same.

Comment: I did it with the import that you told me in the .kt and tried to run it but it doesn't work

Comment: what did you pass to my function exactly? did you do it just like I said? did you pass the main layout of all views in your XML file to the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212664/discussion-between-jorgealberto-and-amir-hossein).

Comment: I already posted what you told me in chat but it changed the background of just that layout, how can I keep that background on all the layouts of the app?

Comment: ok then you have to use tag for each button and the method I have send you in chat you can make an if for the View entry's tag and decide on which color have to be.

Answer (score 0):

you can set image programmatically on click of that imageView

```
imageView41.setOnClickListener {

            imageView41.setImageResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)

            //setBackgroundResource change the background of the imageView            
            imageView41.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo);

    }
```

Comment: Where do I need to add it? in the .kt?

Comment: Yes, If you are using java then you have to convert the code to java

Comment: Yeah I'm using kotlin

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you? @JorgeAlberto

Comment: What do you want to change the background or resources of the imageView? @JorgeAlberto

Comment: I want to change the background resources when I click the imageView

Comment: Do you mean to replace drawable amarillo to fondoamarillo ? @JorgeAlberto

Comment: No, I want to replace the actual background fondoazul.jpg to a new background fondoamarillo.jpg, the drawable amarillo is the image of the imageView but I want to click that imageView "that's the preview" to change the background to fondoamarillo.jpg

Comment: If I add it on the .kt it says Unresolved reference: imageView41

Comment: fun onCambio(view: View){

        imageView41.setOnClickListener {

        imageView41.setImageResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)

        //setBackgroundResource change the background of the imageView
        imageView41.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo);

    }}

Comment: Please update your question with latest code @JorgeAlberto

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about what you want to achieve. If you just want to change the background of you imageview41 you can try

```
fun onCambio(view: View) {
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)

    //setBackgroundResource change the background of the imageView
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoamarillo);
}}
```

since you are referencing `onCambio` in the xml, I think you do not need to set an onClickListener in kotlin. But mind that this will only change the background of that one view and not "all the layers" as you say.

If what you want to do is change the background of the entire screen you should maybe change the background of the viewgroup holding your imageview instead of changing the background of the imageview itself.

if you want this change to persist across activities you have to store a reference to the desired background resource in persistent memory. you can achieve this by storing the resource id of your background drawable in shared preferences.

(si querés escribime en el chat pq me temo q no se esta entendiendo bien lo q querés alcanzar)

Answer (score 0):

> I think this will work

```
 imageView41.setOnClickListener {
            colores.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)
        }
```

> otherwise

```
fun onCambio(view: View){

colores.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.fondoamarillo)

}}
```

Your question is still unclear for me.

for what i understand  you have `imageView(@+id/imageView41)` that show yellow color
after you click the `imageView(@+id/imageView41)` it would change `layer or layout?(@+id/colores)`
to be fondoamarillo.jpg
you also mention that your kt is named "Colores"

something still unclear for me is

> what is your Colores.kt do?

if you really need help I believe you need to show your MainActivity or the Activity that want to click this image and also the layout xml file
and the Colores.kt too

Comment: what is your button id that you want to click and change the background?  I thought it's  android:id="@+id/imageView41" no?